# Creating array size of passed value gives garbage value

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int higher_element = arr[0];

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if(arr[i] > higher_element)
        higher_element = arr[i];

cout << "Higher element in an unsorted array :" << higher_element << endl;

int Hash[higher_element] = {0};
```

Here I want to create a new array of size `higher_element` and initialize it to `0` but array is not creating, only a garbage value is created.

The output of the `higher element` is `12`.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `int Hash[higher_element]={0};` in `c++` the size of this type of array must be a compile time constant. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: See operators `new []` and `delete[]`.

Comment: Note the C++ compilers that I know of with support for variable length arrays do not zero-initialize the entire array when you `int Hash[higher_element]={0};`. The first element is zeroed, the rest are not. This is the price of using non-standard extensions. The behaviour's not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C++, I suggest you to use `vector`.
Here's the `std::vector` solution for your problem.

```
std::vector<int> Hash(higher_element);
```

Vectors initialize to 0 automatically. But for your clarification,

```
std::vector<int> Hash(higher_element,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use const in declaring the array.

If you want to use a variable to define the size of the array, try this

```
int *Hash;
Hash = new int[higher_element];
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: This is wrong because you failed to `delete []` it later.  Better to use `std::make_unique<int[]>(higher_element)` because that returns a smart pointer that will take care of deletion for you (even in cases of abnormal return like exceptions)

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I have described the basic use of the new operator. In that program, we have to use the delete operator to destroy the malloced array.

Comment: Terminology warning: The above comment is misleading. Do not `delete` `malloc`ed storage.